# Insert a custom labels in a property of lwc in Experience builder

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-experience, customlabel, experience-builder-page

I'm trying to put a custom label for an exposed property of a lwc in Experience Builder.

If I have a custom label called Date, what I have to insert in Experience Builder?

```
//mylwc.js-meta.xml
<property name="labelDate" type="String" label="Filter: Date" default="{!$Label.Date}" /> 


//mylwc.js
@api labelDate;
```

In documentation I find this way to refer custom labels: {!$Label.Date}, but I also try {!Label.c.Date} where c is the namespace.

And in Experience Builder I try this format, but it doesn't work.

[image: Experience builder]

Is it possible do this thing? Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: have you tried default={!$Label.Date}?

Comment: I can't: Open quote is expected for attribute "default" associated with an  element type  "property".

Comment: This may not be possible directly in LWC - see the accepted answer here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/317434/is-it-possible-to-import-a-dynamic-custom-label-in-lwc-js

Comment: I hope you have already imported the label in JS before using it. As explained [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_labels)

Comment: But I don't want to import the label and use it in template. I want to write in Experience Builder the custom label name (instead of a simple string) as a property. I don't know if there is a notation like visualforce (for example {!$Label.Date}) or this is not possible.
So my question is: There is an expression to refer a custom label in Experience builder?

Comment: And did you try {label.date} as mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: Can you please link me the reference?

Comment: [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_labels)